# I implemented facebook login and google login facebook login is not working but google login is working

Tags: php, google-app-engine, gwt, facebook-javascript-sdk, google-signin

Hi im implemented both Login facebook and google login for my webpage.

Normally facebook login was working before when i implemented. Then after i implemented and use google login.

I got error like this my system is php

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message
>   'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'' in
>   /hermes/bosnaweb09a/b1040/ipg.kazaniocom/google-login-api/libraries/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php:125
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /hermes/bosnaweb09a/b1040/ipg.kazaniocom/google-login-api/libraries/Google/Client.php(128):
>   Google_Auth_OAuth2->authenticate('AQB-efkOtXD2MPr...', false) #1
>   /hermes/bosnaweb09a/b1040/ipg.kazaniocom/google-login-api/index.php(56):
>   Google_Client->authenticate('AQB-efkOtXD2MPr...') #2
>   /hermes/bosnaweb09a/b1040/ipg.kazaniocom/register.php(2):
>   include('/hermes/bosnawe...') #3 {main} thrown in
>   /hermes/bosnaweb09a/b1040/ipg.kazaniocom/google-login-api/libraries/Google/Auth/OAuth2.php
>   on line 125

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function check_username(){var b=$('#username').val();if(b.length<3){$('#username').css('border','2px solid #a50000')}else{$.get("system/ajax.php?a=checkUser",{data:b},function(a){if(a==1){$('#username').css('border','2px solid #00a500')}else{$('#username').css('border','2px solid #a50000')}})}}function check_email(){var b=$('#email').val();if(b.length<3){$('#email').css('border','2px solid #a50000')}else{$.get("system/ajax.php?a=checkEmail",{data:b},function(a){if(a==1){$('#email').css('border','2px solid #00a500')}else{$('#email').css('border','2px solid #a50000')}})}}function check_email2(){var a=new RegExp(/^(("[\w-+\s]+")|([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*)|("[\w-+\s]+")([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*))(@((?:[\w-+]+\.)*\w[\w-+]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][\d]\.|1[\d]{2}\.|[\d]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\]?$)/i);var b=$('#email').val();var c=$('#email2').val();if(!a.test(c)){$('#email2').css('border','2px solid #a50000')}else if(b==c){$('#email2').css('border','2px solid #00a500')}else{$('#email2').css('border','2px solid #a50000')}}




$starttime = microtime(true);
define('BASEPATH', true);
include('system/config.php');

if(isset($google_user)){
    //print_r($google_user);
    $user_profile = $google_user;
    $user_profile['first_name'] = $google_user['givenName'];
    $login_through = "Google";
} else {
    $login_through = "Facebook";
}







<?php

  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope"=>"user_birthday,email,user_friends,user_relationships,user_hometown,user_education_history,user_work_history"));
  ?><a href="<?php echo $loginUrl;?>"><img src="img/fbcb.png" width="171" /></a><a href="<?php echo $google_login; ?>"><img src="img/gcb.png" width="205" /></a><?php

/*echo "<pre>";
print_r($lang);
print_r($user_profile);
echo "</pre>";*/

?>
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use the Google API Client to authorize to Facebook if your description is accurate. Posting the actual code where the auth is happening and the auth endpoint URL would help more.

Comment: Hi adam  as you can see oauth is i believe is making here but im not so experienced so im amateur lets say it is my first trying [link]https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=1578607125746026&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.kazanio.com%2Fregister.php&state=7c4c9d8f10bcdadc31faf55d1f43a426&sdk=php-sdk-3.2.3&scope=user_birthday%2Cemail%2Cuser_friends%2Cuser_relationships%2Cuser_hometown%2Cuser_education_history%2Cuser_work_history[link]